# How to create a theme with a picture panel svg or png for GNOME Flashback (Compiz), Unity, Gnome Classic?

Tags: unity, themes, panel, gtk3

How to create a theme with a picture panel svg or png for GNOME Flashback (Compiz) and GNOME Flashback (Metacity) and Unity in Ubuntu 14.04.

How to create a theme with a picture panel (svg or png) for Unity and Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 12.04.

I can not get gnome-panel.css unity.css and image display panel. 
This is easily done in GTK 2. Is it possible to GTK 3?

Give reference to exemplary themes which are correctly displayed panel with image svg or png.